# EJB client jar causes TOMEE9 to deploy EJB

Tags: ejb-3.0, apache-tomee

In the TOMEE 9 console log, I am seeing EJB3 beans being deployed on a my Web application. This web application has an EJB client jar in its class path. But it seems wrong for this web app to deployed the EJB since it is an EJB client, not an EJB server.  Am I doing something wrong?

Here is what I see in the log:

```
Jun 21, 2023 2:36:27 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=PaymentManagerBean, ejb-name=PaymentManagerBean, container=My Stateless Container)
Jun 21, 2023 2:36:27 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=IRMTransactionManagerBean, ejb-name=IRMTransactionManagerBean, container=My Stateless Container)
Jun 21, 2023 2:36:27 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=GraphManagerBean, ejb-name=GraphManagerBean, container=My Stateless Container)
Jun 21, 2023 2:36:27 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=ReportManagerBean, ejb-name=ReportManagerBean, container=My Stateless Container)
Jun 21, 2023 2:36:27 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=DeviceManagerBean, ejb-name=DeviceManagerBean, container=My Stateless Container)
```

Comment: Double check if you dont have ejb classes somewhere in libs or classpath. Your ejb client jar should contain only interfaces.

Comment: For some reasons, "maven-ejb-plugin" will include the ejb classes in the client jar file if "<clientExcludes>" is used.  So, I made some configure changes to this plugin and it is working now.